# Convert javascript object to polars dataframe in node.js and populate missing values with null

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-polars

I'm trying to use [`nodejs-polars`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/nodejs-polars/html/index.html) library but have encountered a problem converting a *javascript* object to a *polars* dataframe.

Consider the following data for example

```js
const myData = [
    {
        "id": "a",
        "name": "fred",
        "country": "france",
        "age": 30,
        "city": "paris" // there's no "city" property elsewhere in `myData`
    },
    {
        "id": "b",
        "name": "alexandra",
        "country": "usa",
        "age": 40
    },
    {
        "id": "c",
        "name": "george",
        "country": "argentina",
        "age": 50
    }
]
```

So if we do

```js
const pl = require("nodejs-polars")

const output = pl.DataFrame(myData)
```

We get the error:

> Error: Lengths don't match: Could not create a new DataFrame from Series. The Series have different lengths

Is there no way to create a *polars* dataframe from object such that it will automatically populate missing values with `null`?

Comment: Could you make a `nodejs-tag`? You have the rights to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is not currently supported using `pl.Dataframe`, the desired behavior is supported via `pl.readJSON`. If you don't mind doing a small amount of pre-processing, this is easily achievable

```js
const ndJSONData = myData
  .map(row => JSON.stringify(row))
  .join("\n")

// -1 will do a full scan, set to a length that best fits your use case.
const df = pl.readJSON(ndJSONData, {"inferSchemaLength": -1})
```

**Edit:**
This is now supported with newer versions of polars via `readRecords`. nested dtypes do have limited support.

```js
const df = pl.readRecords(myData, {inferSchemaLength: 10)
```